# Unable to debug in pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to debug python code in pycharm and I get the following error when I try to.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 49657 --file "Python 27"
pydev debugger: process 469 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 133.881)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1534, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1145, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Python 27'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is a screenshot of the settings on pycharm. 
[image]

Comment: What's that "Python 27" in the "Script" field?

Comment: Not sure... Should I remove it. I am newbie to python

Comment: Ok, you should choose a script to run/debug in this field.